# Безопасный аплоад

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Требуется разрешить аплоад только картинок и архивов с картинками.
Как безопасно и достоверно проверить файл на картинку? 
Прочитал вот эту статейку: http://habrahabr.ru/post/148999/

Автор прав, но не предлагает никакого решения. 
Пока что проверку на картинку вроде как предлагается проверять ресайзом. Если ресайз успешен, то это картинка.
Что можете посоветовать?

UPDATE:
Вот, что пока что надумалось/насобиралось:

1. В папке upload запретить выполнение скриптов
2. Папка upload недоступна из "вне"
3. На весь проект разрешить выполнение только *.php (ну или если еще какие используются, то их тоже), чтоб юзер не смог запустить *.jpg
4. Картинку пересохранять, чтоб отбросился возможный мусор (правда не нашел "кто" точно это сделает)
5. Имя файла уникальное (типа md5(microtime(true))), чтоб юзер не знал даже имени на сервере
6. Расширение назначать исходя из image_type_to_extension, а не доверять полбзовательскому.
7. Взаимоисключает 6-ой пункт. Все картинки приводить к JPG например.

Если еще есть предложения, то прошу их озвучить.

Comment: Понадобится темная комната, экран, проектор и фотокамера. Загруженную картину проецировать на экран и фотографировать на камеру. Только так.

Ну или то же в цифровом виде: вытащить из загруженного файла изображение и пересохранить его - с помощью GD или imageMagick

Comment: Попутно можно начать писать свой антивирус, который бы искал "признаки" злого кода в принятых данных – строки типа "`<?php`", "`<?`".

Comment: @ray_ban, храните картинки на отдельном поддомене, где запрещено выполнение любых скриптов.

Comment: @ray_ban, достаточно трех вещей:

* Проверки расширения, чтобы случайно не подхватить js
* Проверки заголовков файла, хоть через ту же функцию getimagesize
* Принудительного убирания исполняемого бита

Теоретически после этого злоумышленник сможет закодировать код, проставив ему валидные заголовки и заинклюдив *тело изображения* в другом месте (и от этого никак не застраховаться), но если у него есть возможность инклюдить, скорее всего, он уже имеет доступ к выполнению любого php-кода.